# How to show an image with transparent background with PIL- python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm doing a project, and trying to insert an image that has a transparent background, but even putting it in PNG, the background keeps showing up.

My code:

```
img = Image.open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projeto Python\ball.png")
img = img.resize((50,50), Image.ANTIALIAS)
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
tk.Label(root, image=tkimage).place(x = 320, y =20)
```

how it appears:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnGPS.png)

Is there any other way to make the background transparent?

Comment: tkinter widgets do not support transparent background.  However you can draw the transparent image inside a `Canvas` widget.